# Fluttertoast.showToast - how center text inside toast

Tags: flutter, toast

I´m using `Fluttertoast.showToast` to show quickly warnings:

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'text',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          textColor: Colors.black,
      );
```

The text doesn't appears centered inside the box.
Any tip?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7rjC.jpg)

Comment: Text of Fluttertoast is already in the center I think

Comment: Attach an image of what you are having.

Comment: pls, see attached image. The toast box is orange.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this parameters : `webPosition: "center"`

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'text',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 3,
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          webPosition: "center"
      );
```

Comment: hi Windsor_Elliot, I updated my toast version from "fluttertoast: ^3.1.3" to  "fluttertoast: ^4.0.0", because webPositon works only in 4.0.0, but, doesnt works yet. Please, another tip? Thanks